# python selenium bs4, download image not from https url but from src with server dir

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I want to automate downloading some images from website

I finally approached and got the src of the image

```
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
td_soup = soup.find('td', {'colspan' : '8'})
src = td_soup.find('img').get('src')
```

but the thing is, when I print(src), this is what I got

```
'/CtxApp/resource/6/1566779160637815196.jpg'
```

I have not much knowledge on web in general but as I think that src is standing for directory of the image of the server.

in this case, is there any way i can downlaod this file?
I looked up many questions on downloading just common http urls but not of this case.
If I try to download the file as they suggested, I get below

```
ValueError: unknown url type: '/CtxApp/resource/6/1566779160637815196.jpg'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add base URL to this string.

`base_url` - URL where from you take images.For example:
`base_url = https://images.unsplash.com` - you want to take an image from this website.
`Beautiful soup` return link as `/photo-1568312442641-d6c790fdf0f6`,

```
src = /photo-1568312442641-d6c790fdf0f6
ready_img_link = base_url + src
```

`ready_img_link` will be `https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1568312442641-d6c790fdf0f6`
Please read this article - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Generic_syntax